# ChoiceBox inside a TableView's cell only through custom Callback

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, tableview

I have been using a custom cell factory to display a `ChoiceBox` inside a `TableView`'s `TableColumn`'s cell, i.e.

```
someColumn.setCellFactory(new DayCellFactory());
```

with `DayCellFactory` implementing `Callback` (with the `call` and `updateItem` methods), and the `ChoiceBox`'s (and thus the cell's) value being bound to the value of a property. The `ChoiceBox` shows the potential values of the enum `Day`.

```
class DayCellFactory implements Callback<TableColumn<DayPeriod, Day>, TableCell<DayPeriod, Day>> {

    private final static ObservableList<Day>    list    = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    static {
        for (Day day : Day.values()) {
            list.add(day);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public TableCell<DayPeriod, Day> call (TableColumn<DayPeriod, Day> column) {
        return new TableCell<DayPeriod, Day>() {

            @Override
            public void updateItem (Day item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (!empty) {
                    ObservableValue<Day> obsVal = getTableColumn().getCellObservableValue(getIndex());
                    ObjectProperty<Day> objProp = (ObjectProperty<Day>) obsVal;

                    ChoiceBox<Day> choice = new ChoiceBox<>(list);
                    choice.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(objProp);

                    setGraphic(choice);
                }
            }
        };
    }

}
```

I thought I could reduce the code by simply using

```
someColumn.setCellFactory(ChoiceBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(list));
```

(with the `list` defined and filled as required) but the resulting cell looks (and behaves) like a simple label showing the property's `toString()` value - yes, I did click there, but no `ChoiceBox` appears. And removing this line makes no difference. Removing the cell value factory results in no value being displayed.

I guess that there is no binding taking place with this simple approach, but this can probably be taken care of as well. It just seems strange that there is no `ChoiceBox` appearing.

Comment: Forgive the "is it turned on" question, but did you call `setEditable(true)` on the `TableView`?

Comment: Also, in your custom implementation (which you might still prefer), you have a bug that could be quite tricky. If the cell is reused from one item to another (eg when the user scrolls), then the bidirectional binding from the old item will still be present, as well as the bidirectional binding to the new item. You need to arrange to remove old bidirectional bindings.

Comment: @James_D The `setEditable(true)` is not used, and `someColumn.setEditable(true)` does not affect anything.

Comment: You need to call setEditable(true) on the *table*, not on the column. Tables are not editable by default (columns are). Your custom cell doesn't invoke the standard editing mechanisms, so it doesn't matter there, but the ChoiceBoxTableCell does need it.

Comment: Strange ... now the `ChoiceBox` appears when I click 3 times on the label. After the first click, the row gets selected but the color of the font is white like the other entries which do not work with boxes. The font in the box of a different column (created with the custom approach) gets black. After the second click, its color does get black, but the `ComboBox`is not yet visible. Only after the third click does it appear.